# pytesseract: Can't access Image with "Image.open" "Errno 2" error

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use `pytesseract` for the first time. I'm also not so confortable with python. I've created a new folder called `python_test` on my desktop. I'm on Mac. In this folder I have a `test.png` file and a py script :

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image

print image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
print image_to_string(Image.open('test-english.jpg'), lang='eng')
```

So from my terminal, I'm going into the python_test folder then I'm running `python read.py` then I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 4, in <module>
    print image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
  File "/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What I'am doing wrong ?

Comment: how can I find the absolute path to the file ? I mean what does it looks like ?  how should I add it in my python file ? is this something like this `~/users/desktop/python_test/test.png'` ?

Comment: I also tried this `print image_to_string(Image.open(os.path.abspath("python_test/test.png")))`

Comment: I got the same problem as you. I don't understand why but installing the `tesseract-ocr` package fixed it (that's what it's called on ubuntu anyway). I already had the `pytesseract` pypi package, but not the underlying library. I suggest trying that. If it fixes it, an image load error is a very mysterious side effect of not having the package installed.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks it worked :) you should propose this as an answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error as you, installing the `tesseract` package fixed it (or `tesseract-ocr` on debian/ubuntu). It contains the native code library used under the hood by `pytesseract`.

An image load error seems like an odd way for the library to fail if the underlying native library is not installed, but there you go.

To install use commands (insert sudo as appropriate)

macos

```
brew install tesseract
```

ubuntu

```
apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the error when I used first time `image_to_string`.

You have to change the the following line in the `pytesseract.py` file.

```
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
```

*Note: I'm using windows.*

Comment: So where exactly my tesseract located? I dont know where. I have just installed pytesseract and python.

Comment: Thanks, after isntalling the windows version of tesseract-ocr (that pytesseract doesn't bother to check for or catch errors...) I used 
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
And pytesseract lives somewhere like 
C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract>